# Will More vCPU's and RAM Help Protect Against Some Smaller Scale DDoS Attacks?

Tags: memory, ddos, denial-of-service, vcpu

**Obviously having more vCPU's (virtual CPU's) and more RAM by them self won't be able to alone help stop and/or prevent a DDoS attack**, but let's say after a DDoS attack is finished and/or slowing down would having more vCPU's and RAM dedicated to a server help recover from the attack faster?